# `h:commandLink` action is not invoked ( maybe because of `ui:repeat`)

Tags: jsf

Here is code:

```
<ui:repeat var="entity" varStatus="status" value="#{myentityListView.someList}">

                <h:form>
                <h:commandLink  value="Go!" action="mypage.xhtml" >
                <c:if test="#{entity.entityType=='Comment'}"><f:param  name="productId" value="#{entity.product.getId()}"/></c:if>
                <f:param  name="userId" value="#{entity.user.getId()}"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                 </h:form>

                </ui:repeat>
```

Maybe its cause is that `h:commandLink` is in `ui:repeat`.

mypage.xhtml is an exixting page.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked). I by the way suggest to just use `<h:link>` instead.

Comment: thanks @BalusC but they are in different h:form s, tried your answer, did not work

Comment: Point 4 of that answer applies as good.

Comment: I posted an answer anyway, this way I can show the proper approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `#{myentityListView.someList}` returns **exactly** the same value during the form submit request as it was during the request of displaying the page. Putting the bean in the view scope (just mark it `@ViewScoped`) and ensuring that you preserve the list during (post)constructor or in an action method should fix it.

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

However, in *your particular case*, it's much better to just use `<h:link>` instead as you don't seem to need to send a POST request at all. This way you end up with nice bookmarkable and searchbot-chipherable links.

```
<ui:repeat var="entity" varStatus="status" value="#{myentityListView.someList}">
    <h:form>
        <h:link value="Go!" outcome="mypage.xhtml">
            <f:param name="userId" value="#{entity.user.id}" />
            <f:param name="productId" value="#{entity.product.id}" disable="#{entity.entityType != 'Comment'}" />
        </h:link>
    </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

Also note that I fixed your `<c:if>` approach by removing it as it won't work as you'd expect. It would always evaluate `false`. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)